# How to fetch or retreive large data from Mongo DB to Front end in java?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jsp, controller

I have a collection with 50,000 records in MongoDB.When i try to show it in the web page.It takes a lot of time(around 7 mins for 15000 records)

I have already tried with Indexing,But it doesnot work.I have written a method in controller to fetch the data from XYZ collection(I am reading 500 records at a time in loop).And I am calling that method in the method in the front end and using its data to display.

This is my Controller method:
**Maincontroller.java:**

```
public List<Data> getDataBetweenDates(String startDate, String endDate) {
        List<Data> DataList = null;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        // change regex accordingly
        String[] start = startDate.split("-");
        String[] end = endDate.split("-");
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(start[0]));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(start[1]) - 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(start[2]));

        String startDateInMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis() + "";

        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(end[0]));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(end[1]) - 1);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(end[2]));

        String endDateInMillis = cal.getTimeInMillis() + "";

        System.out.println("start = " + startDateInMillis + "  end = " + endDateInMillis);

        try {
            DataList = DataDao.getDataBetweenDates(startDateInMillis, endDateInMillis);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return DataList;
    }
```

This is the Dao method Implementation:

```
@Override
    public List<Data> getDataBetweenDates(String startDate, String endDate) throws Exception {
        List<Data> DataList = new ArrayList<>();

        JSONObject jObj = null;
        JSONObject query = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject start = new JSONObject();

        start.put("$gte",startDate);
        start.put("$lte", endDate);

        query.put("timestamp", start);


        long totalCount = dbService.count(Data.COLLECTION, query);

        for(int j = 0 ; j <= totalCount; j+=500){

             jObj = dbService.find(Data.COLLECTION, query, new JSONObject(),new JSONObject(),j,500);


             if (!jObj.has("value")) {
                      return DataList;
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < jObj.getJSONArray("value").length(); i++) {
                        Data  Data = gson.fromJson(jObj.getJSONArray("value").getJSONObject(i).toString(), Data.class);
                        DataList.add(Data);
                    }
        }   

        jObj = null;
        query = null;

        return DataList;
    }
```

Is there any way that i can reduce the loading time.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use paging?

Comment: @TwITe I am already using it sir.I am using bootstrap 3 with datatables(which has auto paging).